# Altair GraphiQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql

I'm learning graphQL API for Ruby on Rails applications, and trying to learn how to use Altair. I'm confused on how to get the schema into Altair for me to test out queries. When I input the link `http://localhost:3000/graphiql` in Altair like so:

[image]

It gives me this error message:

```
{
  "status": 404,
  "error": "Not Found",
  "exception": "#<ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [POST] \"/graphiql\">",
  "traces": {
    "Application Trace": [],
    "Framework Trace": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "trace": "actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:63:in `call'"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "trace": "actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "trace": "railties (5.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "trace": "railties (5.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "trace": "activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'"
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "trace": "activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'"
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "trace": "activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'"
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "trace": "railties (5.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'"
      },
      {
        "id": 8,
        "trace": "actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'"
      },
      {
        "id": 9,
        "trace": "actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'"
      },
      {
        "id": 10,
        "trace": "rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'"
      },
      {
        "id": 11,
        "trace": "activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'"
      },
      {
        "id": 12,
        "trace": "actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'"
      },
      {
        "id": 13,
        "trace": "actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'"
      },
      {
        "id": 14,
        "trace": "static-rails (0.1.0) lib/static-rails/site_middleware.rb:17:in `call'"
      },
      {
        "id": 15,
        "trace": "rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'"
      },
      {
        "id": 16,
        "trace": "rack-cors (1.1.1) lib/rack/cors.rb:100:in `call'"
      },
      {
        "id": 17,
        "trace": "railties (5.1.7) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'"
      },
      {
        "id": 18,
        "trace": "puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'"
      },
      {
        "id": 19,
        "trace": "puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/server.rb:706:in `handle_request'"
      },
      {
        "id": 20,
        "trace": "puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/server.rb:476:in `process_client'"
      },
      {
        "id": 21,
        "trace": "puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/server.rb:334:in `block in run'"
      },
      {
        "id": 22,
        "trace": "puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'"
      }
    ],
    "Full Trace": [
      {
        "id": 0,
        "trace": "actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:63:in `call'"
      },
      {
        "id": 1,
        "trace": "actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'"
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "trace": "railties (5.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'"
      },
      {
        "id": 3,
        "trace": "railties (5.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'"
      },
      {
        "id": 4,
        "trace": "activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `block in tagged'"
      },
      {
        "id": 5,
        "trace": "activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'"
      },
      {
        "id": 6,
        "trace": "activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:69:in `tagged'"
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "trace": "railties (5.1.7) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'"
      },
      {
        "id": 8,
        "trace": "actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'"
      },
      {
        "id": 9,
        "trace": "actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:25:in `call'"
      },
      {
        "id": 10,
        "trace": "rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'"
      },
      {
        "id": 11,
        "trace": "activesupport (5.1.7) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:27:in `call'"
      },
      {
        "id": 12,
        "trace": "actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'"
      },
      {
        "id": 13,
        "trace": "actionpack (5.1.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:125:in `call'"
      },
      {
        "id": 14,
        "trace": "static-rails (0.1.0) lib/static-rails/site_middleware.rb:17:in `call'"
      },
      {
        "id": 15,
        "trace": "rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'"
      },
      {
        "id": 16,
        "trace": "rack-cors (1.1.1) lib/rack/cors.rb:100:in `call'"
      },
      {
        "id": 17,
        "trace": "railties (5.1.7) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'"
      },
      {
        "id": 18,
        "trace": "puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'"
      },
      {
        "id": 19,
        "trace": "puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/server.rb:706:in `handle_request'"
      },
      {
        "id": 20,
        "trace": "puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/server.rb:476:in `process_client'"
      },
      {
        "id": 21,
        "trace": "puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/server.rb:334:in `block in run'"
      },
      {
        "id": 22,
        "trace": "puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Based on the error message I thought it would have something to do with my `routes.rb` file but i'm not sure what so here it is:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  post "/graphql", to: "graphql#execute"

  if Rails.env.development?
    mount GraphiQL::Rails::Engine, at: '/graphiql', graphql_path: '/graphql'

    root to: redirect('/graphiql')
  end
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

Also my development environment is Ubuntu on Windows. Thank you for the help.

Comment: "/graphiql" is a GET route that you can visit in the browser. "/graphql" is your POST route. If you want to send a POST request then you have to send it to "/graphql"

Comment: Thank you, fixing it to "graphql" worked!